# Azure - Check if a new blob is uploaded to a container

Tags: azure, containers

Are there ways to check if a container in Azure has a new blob (doesn't matter which blob it is)? LastModifiedUtc does not seem to change if a blob is dropped into the container

Comment: I had believed that the blob container ETag property should do what you need, but I just tried that out and it doesn't appear to update when a file is uploaded. I've deleted my answer for now and will investigate a little more.

Comment: Yes, both Properties (LastModifiedUtc and ETag) on the container don't seem to get updated on file/blob upload to a container.

Comment: I'm actually wondering if this is a recent bug - I wasn't able to make those properties update, no matter what I did, yet I've seen plenty of posts where people say to use these properties for exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Azure Blob Storage does not provide this functionality out of the box. You would need to handle this on your end. A few things come to my mind (just thinking out loud):

- If the blobs are uploaded using your application (and not through 3rd party tools), after the blob is uploaded, you could just update the container properties (may be add/update a metadata entry with information about the last blob uploaded). You could also make an entry into Azure Table Storage and keep on updating it with the information about last blob uploaded. As I said above, this method will only work if all blobs are uploaded through your application.
- You could manually iterate through blobs in the blob container periodically and then sort them by last modified date. This method would work fine for a blob container having lesser number of blobs. If the number of blobs are more (say in tens of thousands), then you would end up fetching a long list because blob storage only sorts the blob by blob name.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a BlobTrigger function in an App Service resource.

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob)